# How to have cli-spinner run during ShellJS command exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, shelljs

I'm currently trying to make a simple command-line node program that allows for me to easily create a boilerplate for a lot of the React/Redux applications that I make. I'm using [ShellJS](http://shelljs.org) to execute console commands (I've tried using [Node's child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), too.) The problem is getting [cli-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-spinner) to work with executing terminal commands. Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
var shell = require('shelljs');
var userArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
var folderName = userArgs[0];
var Spinner = require('cli-spinner').Spinner;
var depSpin = new Spinner('Installing dependencies.. %s');
depSpin.setSpinnerString(10);

shell.mkdir(folderName);
shell.cd(folderName);

depSpin.start(); 
// I expect for the spinner to start here (before the execution of the commands.)

shell.exec('npm init -y', {silent: true});
shell.exec('npm install --save babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react react-dom react-redux redux webpack', {silent: true});
shell.exec('npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env webpack-dev-server', {silent: true});

depSpin.stop(); 
// Since ShellJS should run synchronously, 
// the spinner should stop right after the last command finishes.

shell.touch('webpack.config.js');
shell.mkdir(['build', 'frontend']);

shell.cd('frontend');
shell.mkdir(['components', 'containers', 'reducers', 'store']);
shell.touch('app.js');
```

But when running the program, it just hangs without displaying anything while it installs the dependencies. It's the same as when the spinner code wasn't even in there. I've also tried removing the `depSpin.stop()`, which just makes the program hang forever on the spinner. I have a feeling that this issue is caused by a conflict between `cli-spinner` and `ShellJS` both using the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this effect by using `child_process`'s `spawn`. I had to create a `child_process.spawn` and run all of the commands concatenated with `&&`. That freed up the console output to be exclusively the `cli-spinner` output. I then did an event handler for when the child process exited to stop the spinner.

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
var shell = require('shelljs');
var userArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
var folderName = userArgs[0];
var Spinner = require('cli-spinner').Spinner;
var depSpin = new Spinner('Installing dependencies.. %s');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var commandsDep = [
  'cd ' + folderName,
  'npm init -y',
  'npm install --save babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react react-dom react-redux redux webpack',
  'npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env webpack-dev-server'
];
var depChild = spawn(commandsDep.join(' && '), {
  shell: true
});
depSpin.setSpinnerString(18);

shell.mkdir(folderName);
shell.cd(folderName);

depSpin.start();
depChild.on('exit', () => {
  depSpin.stop();
  shell.exec('clear');
  console.log('Installing dependencies.. ✓');
})

shell.touch('webpack.config.js');
shell.mkdir(['build', 'frontend']);

shell.cd('frontend');
shell.mkdir(['components', 'containers', 'reducers', 'store']);
shell.touch('app.js');

shell.cd('containers');
shell.touch(['AppContainer.js', 'Root.js']);

shell.cd('../reducers');
shell.touch('index.js');

shell.cd('../store');
shell.touch('configureStore.js');
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Owens' answer I made a helper method myself to run long commands with a spinner inline with normal shelljs commands;

```
const Spinner = require('cli-spinner').Spinner;
const spinner = new Spinner('installing.. %s');
spinner.setSpinnerString('|/-\\');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const longCommand = (command, onSuccess) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var process = spawn(command, { shell: true });
      spinner.start();
      process.on('exit', () => {
        spinner.stop();
        onSuccess();
        resolve();
      })
  })
}

const npmInstall = async () => {
  await longCommand("npm install", () => console.log(`NPM modules installed! `))
  // Other stuff
  shell.mkdir('new')
}

npmInstall()
```